# how to tell which disk is sda and which is sdb disk?

Tags: mount, hard-disk, scsi

from the df -k command, I see sda, sdb, sdc disks. They have some partitions (for example, sda has sda1, sda3). I want to detach sdb and sdc temporarily for OS upgrade. How exactly can I tell which disk is which? (actually I know sdc is the disk I recently attached, but how can I tell sda,sdb,sdc, from the SCSI connection? I remember SCSI connectors didn't have any order..)

```
ckim@stph45:/boot/grub] cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: Samsung SSD 850  Rev: EXM0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: ST2000DM001-1CH1 Rev: CC27
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HL-DT-ST Model: BD-RE  BH16NS40  Rev: 1.00
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi4 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: WDC WD100EFAX-68 Rev: 83.H
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
ckim@stph45:/boot/grub] df -k
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       226026064 103433752  111103800  49% /
tmpfs            32958068         0   32958068   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       201454560   4911408  186303152   3% /tools
/dev/sdc1      4806455048 387782752 4174511784   9% /home1
/dev/sdc2      4806466304  18391096 4543914032   1% /home2
/dev/sdb1      1922727280 853724060  971327620  47% /home
```

Comment: If it helps, you can use `lsblk -o +VENDOR,MODEL` which will show you the manufacturer and model number reported by each physical device.  You can also see the serial numbers with `SERIAL`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the make and model of each physical block device with `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk -do +VENDOR,MODEL,SERIAL
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT VENDOR   MODEL            SERIAL
sda    8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk            ATA      WDC WD20EARS-00M WD-WCAZA571XXXX
sdf    8:80   0 465.1G  0 disk            WD       My Passport 070A WD-WXF1A30YXXXX
sr0   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom             HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH22LS40  6FA3D3AFXXXX
sr1   11:1    1   668M  0 rom             WD       Virtual CD 070A  57584631413330593830XXXX
```